# drupal 7 how to add new fields and access them in a custom module form_alter function

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to make some very simple edits to a legacy Drupal 7 project, but having not done anything with Drupal for several years I am stuck on what is probably quite a simple issue.

I am trying to add some extra fields to a form in a custom module.

I have added new fields via admin:

> Home » Administration » Structure » Content types » **MyType**

I now want to be able to use them in the custom module form alter function

```
 fuction ..._form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {}
```

When I try dumping out the content of the $form variable I can see previously existing fields, but I don't seen  any of the new fields I added.

How can I add my fields to the form in my custom module so they can be access via _form_alter

Comment: did you clear bootstrap and registry cache ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First , ensure to all caches was cleared (bootsrap , webform , registry)

Hook definition allow you to check $form_id so ensure you are dumping the right form

```
yourmodulename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  dsm($form_id); // or var_dump($form_id) if you don't have devel module
}
```

or directly make a condition :

```
yourmodulename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == 'myformid') dsm($form); // or var_dump($form) if you don't have devel module
}
```

And if you have more information, add it to post

Comment: Thanks so much for your suggestions!  Caching is something I did not think about.  I will go through your list and get back once I have tried them.

Comment: Thanks again.  I needed both points in the end.  First, two forms with similar names existed so I had altered the wrong one.  Secondly I needed to clear the cache to see the new fields.